# Proper way to implement referential integrity in one-to-many relationship in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

Here is an example:

```
Class Game : Object {
    dynamic var name: String?
    let goals = List<Goal>()
}

Class Goal : Object {
    dynamic var time: NSDate?
    // LinkingObjects here or link to Person?
}
```

What is a best solution for building one to many relationship (ID-dependent), so that `Goal` has only one `Game` as a parent.

In other words to avoid this situation

```
let goal = Goal()
game1.goals.append(goal)
game2.goals.append(goal)
```

I can have a link in `Goal` class to Game, but is it acceptable? Or I should use LinkingObjects (the inverse relationship) somehow?

I'm asking here, because I haven't found any answers in official website unfortunately.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a section called [Inverse Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) in Realm docs

Comment: @Tj3n this section describes how to use LinkingObjects, which is also a kind of array (conforms NSFastEnumaration).

Comment: As you said, it's used for linking back the Goal to the Game, then you can check the property to see if its valid or not to append

Comment: @Tj3n so this is the best solution?

Comment: Yes, the solution @Tj3n mentioned is the best solution. You should give your `Goal` object a property of type `Game?` which points to the game the goal belongs to. Then, if you properly configure a `LinkingObjects` property on your `Game` object, it will automatically contain all the `Goal`s that belong to that `Game`.

Comment: @AustinZ thanks! That's quite a good idea!